# how to use the $_GET superglobal on the php mvc application

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am working on a full blown php mvc application everything about the structure is fine. Except one thing.
Take a look at the code first:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use app\core\route;
use app\controllers\apicontroller;
route::get('/api', [apicontroller::class, 'api']);
```

Now this is the file that i created for all the incoming requests that passes through the application works and pass through here

Now i want a way i would be able to use the $_GET superglobal as a parameter on the route.

Take a look at where i created the route class as a static function

```
namespace app\core;
class route{
    // get request
   public static function get(string $path, callable $method){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $path) {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'GET') {
            exit('This path accepts only GET requests');
        }
        return $method();
    }
   }
   public static function post(string $path,callable $method){
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $path) {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            exit('This path accepts only GET requests');
        }
        return $method();
    }
   }
   }
```

Now all i need is way i can use the route this way:
http:://localhost/api?u=123

To be able to get the parameter from my controller because its not working or let me say is not outputting it

Here is the controller for the apicontroller class:

```
namespace app\controllers;
// use app\core\database;
use app\model\user;
class apicontroller{

public static function api(){
       if(isset($_GET['u'])){
echo $_GET['u'];
// not outputting
}
}
}
```

Comment: Basically you should be able to use `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_FILES`, etc that are super global vars. Except that the framework, or router you use modify these values. You may need to provide more info about framework **name** you use, or what router you are using?

Comment: Okay it is not a popular framework. It is just mvc pattern framework i am creating for my self. So i am just trying to know a way for that $_GET superglobal to work on it

Comment: Make sure that your URL is correct `/api?u=xxx` and it is going into `api()` method. Test by echo something like `echo 'hello';` and then `print_r($_GET);` without any `if` condition. If there is no `hello` text, that means the problem is it does not goes into `api()` method.

Comment: it is going into the api method. But not working for the GET superglobal

Comment: What does `echo 'hello';` and `print_r($_GET);` displayed?

Comment: You can use `print_r($_GET);` in many lines but try it one by one to see that where `$_GET` get replaced its value. Start at before vendor autoload, after autoload, before `route::get()`, inside route class and get method, and many places. Until you found that where it get replaced. From what I see in the code **here** it should work fine without any problem but I think there is something different in your real code that cause this problem but not showing here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should handle the first parameter of yhe get method of your route::class
so that it is variable in appropriate cases
In your route::class:

```
public static function handleGetData($path){
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$getRequest = explode('?' ,$request, 2);
$getData = null;

if (isset($get_request[1])) 
    $getData = '?' . $getRequest[1];

if (!isset($getRequest[1])) 
    $getData = '';

return $path .$getData;
```

}

In your index.php :

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    use app\core\route;
    use app\controllers\apicontroller;

    route::get( route::handleGetData('/api'), [apicontroller::class, 'api']);
```

Now normally your get data will comme and you will be able to handle it in your controller. I think you need to define a 404 method for undefined cases in you route::class